# Can (16 bit) bitwise AND be synthesised from ADD and SUBtract?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have two functions, add and sub, which accept two 16 bit arguments and return 17 bits (result and carry/borrow).

Can I build a bitwise "and" function from these?

(Reasonably small lookup tables, <300 bytes, allowed.  Runtime proportional to number of bits is fine.)

Comment: Do you have any sort of support for conditionals? Any comparisons? Or can you only use expressions consisting of `add`, `sub`, and the two inputs? (If the latter, then I suspect the answer is "no, that's not possible".) Can you actually do anything with the carry/borrow bit?

Comment: Yes, all "normal" flow control is allowed.  The context is writing assembly macros for a homebrew CPU.

Comment: And your homebrew CPU cannot do AND itself???

Comment: What about bitshifts?

Comment: @Aconcagua no, it's very tiny, ~20 chips for 16-bit 7400 design - "and" would take two more chips for the logic and several more for the glue.

Comment: @ruakh (optionally) the carry/borrow bit can be latched in a 1-bit register (Hop) which will cause the Program Counter to increase by 2 before the next fetch, instead of by 1.

Comment: you can subtract with an `add`, so I think you can remove that instruction and replace with a bitwise instruction instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it very hard to guess what your CPU does and does not have, since your question makes it sound like it has basically nothing, but then your follow-up comment seems to take it for granted that it has all the basics.

So, I'll assume the following:

- `add` and `sub`, as provided in the question.
- adequate mechanisms to create a C-style "function", such as:

  - a way to save registers in memory so that they don't get stomped by the function you're calling.
  - a way to take arguments by value, that you can destroy without affecting the caller.
  - a way to return a result to the caller.
- a way to skip a section of logic if one value is less than another (analogous to X86's `jl` "jump if less").

  - I'll write this as `if (a >= b) { ... }`, meaning "if `b` is less than `a`, then jump past the next few instructions; afterward (otherwise), run `...`".
- enough of the basics to support lookup tables of up to 299 bytes, as specified in the question.

Given that, we can write something like this (in C notation):

```
static int const single_bit_values[] = {
    0x8000, 0x4000, 0x2000, 0x1000, 0x0800, 0x0400, 0x0200, 0x0100,
    0x0080, 0x0040, 0x0020, 0x0010, 0x0008, 0x0004, 0x0002, 0x0001
};

int bitwise_and(int operand1, int operand2) {
    int accumulator = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        // set accumulator's bit #i if appropriate:
        if (operand1 >= single_bit_values[i] && operand2 >= single_bit_values[i]) {
            accumulator += single_bit_values[i];
        }

        // clear operands' bit #i:
        if (operand1 >= single_bit_values[i]) {
            operand1 -= single_bit_values[i];
        }
        if (operand2 >= single_bit_values[i]) {
            operand2 -= single_bit_values[i];
        }
    }
    return accumulator;
}
```

Note that, although the above uses `&&` and for-loops, I don't actually assume support for either of those; rather, `if (... && ...)` can easily be expanded into nested ifs, and the for-loop can easily be completely unrolled. But the above version is easier for humans to read.

The way the above works is, it iterates over the single-bit values from high-order bit `10000000 00000000` to low-order bit `00000000 00000001`, and for each one, it sets the corresponding bit in the accumulator if the corresponding bits in the operands are both set. The only tricky part is *how* we check if the two operands are both set; what we do is, we clear each bit in the operands as we complete the corresponding iteration (for example, `11110000 00001111` after three iterations becomes `00010000 00001111`), which then lets us write e.g. `operand1 >= single_bit_values[3]` to mean "`operand1` has bit #3 (the fourth bit) set". (Do you see why?)

Comment: Thanks, all your assumptions are fine.  I'm just seeing if I can get away with an ALU which only does "add" and "sub".  Your answer also gives me the method to also do "or", and I can already do "not" based on "sub".  (Technically I could just get away with "sub", but it's just a little too painful.)